# IBM Worklight App Center not working by using latest version of Chrome APP on Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, google-chrome-app

As usual, user download .apk through IBM App Center, everything work fine until update Chrome app to version **53.0.2785.124**

Nothing happened when user click the download button.

After that, we **downgrade** the Chrome back to the old version, and try it again, .apk downloaded perfectly.

The issue **only** happened on Android device and only Chrome Browser with latest release version 53.0.2785.124 will cause the problem.

( another app like native browser or firefox browser work fine )

All I can do to resolve the problem is downgrade Chrome Browser to older version.

Above all, please someone give some advise or instructions to figure out the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow is not the place for this kind of support for IBM Application Center. As an IBM customer, please open a PMR (support ticket) to contact and receive support from the development team for IBM Application Center.